# Span text across multiple column in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table with 4 columns, and I want text in the first column to span across 3 columns (without merging cells) and also keep the shading of cell. Something like the example below, but I want the text in a single line.

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

This is not very elegant either, but:

1. Create two textboxes, A and B, and in each textbox put a copy of your table.
2. Set the Shape Fill of textbox A to No Fill, and the Shape Outline of both textboxes to No Outline
3. Merge the relevant cells in the table in textbox A, and insert your text
4. Group the textboxes
5. Super-impose textbox A over textbox B so that the tables align exactly.
6. Position the textbox group wherever you need it.

Comment: That's a very clever approach: much better than mine, I must say. My first thought was that it could surely be done without the text boxes (i.e., just by positioning the tables on the page); but it really does work better the way you've written – more manageable. The only thing I did differently when I tested it was to have visible borders in only one of the tables (the bottom one), just in case the tables weren't aligned exactly. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like put the heading text in a text box that has the **Fill** property set to transparent (**No Fill**), and position the text box over the first row of the table, so that the shading and borders show through. Alternatively, merge the cells, add the heading text, and then insert Line shapes that are the same color and width as the table borders, to simulate the vertical grid lines. Neither solution is very elegant, and getting the Line shapes exactly aligned with the vertical borders in the table could be a pain.

If the table spans multiple pages, and you need the first (heading) row to be repeated after the page breaks, you'll have to make sure that your text box or Line shapes are anchored to the paragraph in the first table row, so that they're repeated at the top of the new page.

Here's my hastily made example that uses Line shapes:

[image: Table heading that spans columns with simulated vertical rules]